# Flash AS3 trivia game incorrect answer graphic needs to appear on stage in 3 locations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scoring

I'm creating a trivia game in which a user answers a certain number of questions per round and     if they get 3 wrong they fail the round. When a question is marked as incorrect an x is placed in a box from left to right, each x goes into a box in their own location.

I'm having trouble getting the x's to go to their location, based on the questions answered incorrectly.

Here is an image of the game [image](http://www.noirworldwide.com/pic/maingamescreen.jpg)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var questions:Array=['"I look like a dangling parsnip in this!" she cried. "I will never __________ these jeans!',
                 "Tell the freckled parrot to put his car in __________.",
                 "When purchasing a buttercream trowel, always choose one made of __________.",
                 "Everybody has a cracked snowflake. The question is, __________ one is yours? ",
                 "Standing at the dock, the loopy basket watched the cruise ship set __________ without him. ",];
var answers:Array=[   ["wear","where"], ["idle","idol"], ["steel","steal"] ,[ "which","witch"] ,[ "sail","sale"] ];

var qno=0;var rnd1; var rnd2;
tick.visible=false;cross1.visible=false;
var right_answers=0;var wrong_answers=0;

shade1.buttonMode = true;
shade1.useHandCursor = true;

shade2.buttonMode = true;
shade2.useHandCursor = true;


function change_question(){
if(tick.visible){right_answers++;}
if(cross1.visible){wrong_answers++;}
if(qno==questions.length){gotoAndPlay(60);}else{
tick.visible=false;cross1.visible=false;
rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
q.text=questions[rnd2];
if(questions[rnd2]=="x"){change_question();}
questions[rnd2]="x";
enable_disable(1);
if(rnd1==1){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
if(rnd1==2){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
if(rnd1==3){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
if(rnd1==4){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
if(rnd1==5){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
}}

function enable_disable(a){
if(a==0){shade1.mouseEnabled=false;shade2.mouseEnabled=false;}
if(a==1){shade1.mouseEnabled=true;shade2.mouseEnabled=true;}}

change_question();


shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2);
shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3);


function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==1) {tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade1.y}else{cross1.visible=true;cross1.y=shade1.y}
//qno++;change_question();
}
function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==2){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade2.y}else{cross1.visible=true;cross1.y=428.55}
//qno++;change_question();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not make a movieclip with 4 frames.  frame 1 with nothing in it. frame 2 with 1 x in it. frame 3 with 2 x and frame 4 with 3 x. and just increment the frame as they get it wrong.

Comment: Whenever you can get around doing things the hardway, do it. @The_asMan had a brilliant sollution to your problem.

Comment: @The_asMan That sounds like it will do exactly what I need. Thanks!